# Can someone help me identify this old Shimano derailleur?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, derailleur, derailleur-rear, vintage

I want to poke around online a bit and see if I can find anything out about it. It's a long cage, on an old 18 speed Univega MTB. Thanks. [image: shimano derailleur]

Comment: Look closely at it - there should be a code like    "RD-xxxx"  somewhere.  That will describe it exactly.

Comment: OK, I'll look again. Didn't find it earlier.

Comment: Shimano rear derailleur's have their model number stamped on the bottom of the parallelogram.  Taking off the wheel can give you a better look at that area, which is the opposite side of that shown in your photo.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano#Mountain_groupsets will help narrow it down

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the exact model, but it looks very similar to this one that I found on VeloBase.
If you have the patience check out [this list](http://www.velobase.com/ListComponents.aspx?Category=108). Shimano starts around page 8.
I suspect it might be a bottom of the range version of a Light Action, but I'm far from an expert

EDIT:

I think it might be [this one](http://www.velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=55bf0334-f0fb-4472-b0a1-b92e43abaadd&Enum=108&AbsPos=452). You're fortunate I stumbled across this question when I was in the mood for a bit of a treasure hunt :)

Comment: The problem here is that if the links die, there's no mention of what the derailleur is, it is better to make the answer work without needing to follow the link

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's RD-L541.  And it's paired with a 6-speed cassette, which is consistent.

EDIT:  I should have clicked on the link posted above.  Looks we arrived at the same conclusion.  So, I'll just post a picture.

[image]